# With R, loop over two files at a time

Tags: r, loops

Hello my favourite coding experts,

I am trying to loop through two files at a time in R: i.e. take one 'case' file and another 'control' file, create a graph and dump it into a pdf, then take another set of 2 files and do the same and so on. I have a list indicating which file is a case and which is a control, like this:

```
case   control
A01    G01
A02    G02
A06    G03
```

and so on… which can be reproduced like this: 
   mylist<- data.frame(rbind(c("A01","G01"),c("A02","G02"),c("A06","G03")))
   colnames(mylist)<- c('control', 'case')

I cannot find a way to specify which 2 files to loop through each time. 
The file (each file with many variables) are: "/Users/francy/Desktop/cc_files_A01", ""/Users/francy/Desktop/cc_files_A02", "/Users/francy/Desktop/cc_files_A06", "/Users/francy/Desktop/cc_files_G01", "/Users/francy/Desktop/cc_files_G02", "/Users/francy/Desktop/cc_files_G03"

For each set of case and control, I would like to do this:

```
case<- read.table(file="/Users/francy/Desktop/case_files_A01.txt", sep = '\t', header = F)
case <- case[,c(1,2,19,20)]
colnames(case)<- c("ID", "fname", "lname", "Position")

control<- read.table(file="/Users/francy/Desktop/case_files_G01.txt", sep = '\t', header = F)
control <- control[,c(1,2,19,20)]
colnames(control)<-  c("ID", "fname", "lname", "Position")

#t-test Position: 
test<- t.test(case[20],control[20])
p.value= round(test$p.value, digits=3)
mean_case= round(mean(case[20], na.rm=T), digits=2)
mean_control= round(mean(control[20], na.rm=T), digits=2)

boxplot(c(case[20], control[20]), names=c(paste("case", "mean", mean_case,     sep=":"),paste("control", "mean", mean_control, sep=":")))
```

And want to create a pdf file with all the boxplots.

This is what I have for now:

```
myFiles <- list.files(path= "/mypath/", pattern=".txt")
pdf('/home/graph.pdf')
for (x in myFiles) {
  control <- read.table(file = myFiles[x], sep = '\t', header = F)
  ## How do I specify that is the other file here, and which file it is? 
  case <- read.table(file = myFiles[x], sep = '\t', header = F)
}
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How are the files organized in the directory? Is there some pattern to the filenames, e.g. case1.txt/control1.txt, case2.txt/control2.txt, etc?

Comment: Hi bnaul,unfortunately no pattern...it seems as the letters and numbers are random...

Comment: Many things are confusing here. If you have a list of case and control files, what is the purpose of the `myFiles <- list.files(...)` line, which does not give you information about which file is of which type? Why not just iterate over the list of files that you already have? Or is the problem that the filenames aren't simply 12H.txt, 14C.txt, etc., and so you have to check the files to determine which case/control they correspond to?

Comment: the myFiles has the path to the files, while the case and control file is just specifying which are cases and controls from the last part of the file name, but I can certainly extend this into file names if that helps...

Comment: @user971102 This sounds very strange. It sounds like you're saying that the file names have _no distinguishing pattern_ that would indicate which are cases and controls, or even which are pairs? This will likely only be solvable if you can _clearly_ explain how to tell the difference between the two types based on some characteristic of the file name or contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just pass the pairs of files to the loops via a list?

```
files <- list(
  c("fileA","fileB"),
  c("fileC","fileD")
  )

for( f in files ) {
  cat("~~~~~~~~\n")
  cat("f[1] is",f[1],"~ f[2] is",f[2],"\n")
}
```

The first time the loop runs, `f` contains the 1st element of the list `files`.  Since the first element is a character vector of length two, `f[1]` contains the first file name of the pair, and `f[2]` contains the second.  See the printed output of the above code, which should hopefully make it clear.

Comment: Hi gsk3, this sounds like agood solution for my particular problem...But f[1] gives me both file A and file B files, and then how do I continue the loop by selecting the first file A and doing computations on this one, and then manipulating file B? sorry for the ignorance...

Comment: Thank you gsk3!! Just one last doubt I have...When I run it doing this it only gives me the first two files, while I had specified more in 'files', do you have any idea what is happening? THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH..  :                                     pdf(file='graph') for(f in files ) {
case<- read.table(file = f[2], sep = '\t', header = F)
control<- read.table(file = f[1], sep = '\t', header = F)            boxplot###and other commands###  } dev.off()

Comment: What's the structure of `files`?

Comment: It was something I was doing wrong in the rest of the coding bit, IT WORKS!!! THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of cases and controls is in an R object (dataframe or matrix) called `mylist`:

```
for (x in seq_along(nrow(mylist)) {
  case <- read.table(file = paste("/my/path/", mylist[x, "case"], ".txt", sep = ""),
                       sep = "\t", header = F)
  control <- read.table(file = paste("/my/path/", mylist[x, "control"], ".txt", sep = ""),
                       sep = "\t", header = F)
    ## your code here ##
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler. I am getting errors when I try this code though, I am sure it is because I don't understand it much though.  ex. Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list, and the other errors when I try to continue with my script working with the two data frames 'control' and 'cases' (like when I try to subset the data frames...), do you knwo what I am doing wrong? Thank you again.

Comment: I'm assuming `mylist` is a data.frame or matrix object. If it is a true R `list` type, this will need to be modified at your end to work properly. You didn't provide example code in your question, so we have to guess about what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry Tyler, I edited the post and hope it is a bit clearer now… I am still trying to figure out why the code you suggested is not working for me..I get this error:" In file(file, "rt") : only first element of 'description' argument used"

Answer (score 0):

What probably makes more sense in this case, is building up the two filenames from your "list" (a data.frame?) of cases and controls.

If this "list" is present in a data.frame `lcc`, you could do something like:

```
for(i in seq(nrow(lcc)))
{
  currentcase<-lcc$case[i]
  currentcontrol<-lcc$control[i]
  currentcasefilename<-paste("someprefix_", currentcase, "_somepostfix.txt")
  currentcontrolfilename<-paste("someprefix_", currentcontrol, "_somepostfix.txt")
  #now open and process both files...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick for replying. The cases and controls have all different names without any predictable prefix and postfix though...

Comment: Well, once you've gotten the list of filenames, it should be easy enough to find which ends with (e.g.) "14C.txt", no (if not, check `?grep`)? Just replace the 'paste' trick with the 'find filename ending with' trick.